# Transfer one line of text to another line in the same textfile

Tags: unix

I would like to know if there is a particular code for tranfserring one line of a text to another line in the same text file in Unix? Supposedly i have **Wow.txt** and it contains:

> > The quick brown fox
> >
> > jumps over the lazy dog
>
> The dog is my pet
>
> Oh yeah!

I would like to have an output of:

> > The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>
> The dog is my pet
>
> Oh yeah!

Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: Will there only be a blank line in between or can there be anything?

Comment: no blank lines as much as possible. =)

Comment: Depending on the number of lines and the number of files it might just be easiest to go in by hand and edit them.

Comment: I dont get it. I  am new in unix =) Supposed i have 15 lines in my textfile. and i want to merge line 3 and 4 and retain all untouchable.

Comment: Will it always be line 3 and 4? is there some identifying mark on line 3 that will always be on line 3? (or line 4)

Comment: Not all the times. Just and example only.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cat Wow.txt | tr -d '\n' > Wow-oneline.txt
```

Edit, or for slightly more clean, correct way

```
cat Wow.txt | tr -s '\n' | tr '\n' ' ' > Wow-oneline.txt
```

Edit x2:
If you're going to be doing any significant file processing, I would recommend reading up on [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and/or [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk).

Comment: That would probably result in "foxjumps"

Comment: Hmm. What if i only want to transfer just one line and retain the other lines untouchable? Just see my post i've updated it.

Comment: How is your script supposed to know how many input lines are to be combined into the first output line?

Comment: So, only the first occurrence of lines separated by newlines? Or, only lines with the same indentation?

Comment: @Matthew just ignore the indention. Typo error. =) To give you a clearer view, my text file is a product from a script. I use PuTTY to access those databases. And It displays a some sort of 'Entered Lines' that supposed to be not. Are you getting me? Please tell if you wouldnt have a difficulty in explaining =)

Comment: @Edward am i supposed to know how many lines my text file contains?

Comment: @Kerv, I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I knew it =) u have some sort of other account to have a chat? i'll show you some screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!/^ *$/{print}' < Wow.txt | fmt
```

Comment: There's probably a solution that doesn't involve piping through fmt, but I stopped when I had a solution.

Comment: What if i only want to transfer just one line and retain the other lines untouchable? Just see my post i've updated it.